# Clock indicator has disappeared and nautilus displays with csd

Tags: 16.04, unity, themes, clock, csd

I did 2 things: installed this pack of new light-themes http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/install-improved-ambiance-gnome-theme (which is for 16.10 and 17.04, and I'm on 16.04, I haven't noticed it was incompatible) and updated mesa drivers by adding their ppa and running dist-upgrade.

After reboot the clock indicator has disappeared, nautilus is displaying like in gnome, with *csd* (with ubuntu theme's black corners), desktop icons became enlarged, only "files" section is in global menu, and right click menu wouldn't display some sections, leaving blank space (you can press it, it would work but no text).
After running `sudo apt remove light-themes=16.10+17.10.20170515.1-0ubuntu1` and installing *14.04+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1* it solved only the right click menu problem. Does anybody know what may have caused these problems and how to fix them?

Upd: `Running sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates` returns:

```
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hamish-twaddle/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hamish-twaddle/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Upd2:

```
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hamish-twaddle/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hamish-twaddle/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: So did you install the Mesa drivers from the same PPA or another one?

Comment: And specifically which PPA(s) did you add to your system? That is what did you put after the `sudo apt-add-repository` if you did it that way?

Comment: I used this: ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but due to incompatibilities with the system and just bug in itself, upgrading Mesa probably caused the issues. When I previously upgraded Mesa and my graphics drivers it caused total hell on my machine because Ubuntu has been designed to work certain versions, but not the latest so in many cases it messes everything up.

There is a utility called `ppa-purge`, you may use it in order to downgrade (to the official repository versions) and uninstall all packages from a specific PPA, it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Running:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
```

Should fix your issues, make sure to do a restart after it has finished.

Comment: This command doesn't work. I pasted terminal output here.

Comment: What output do you get from `sudo apt-get update`? Because it doesn't look like `ppa-purge` is failing per say but rather that your configuration is invalid in some way.

Comment: I pasted it here. This is what goes after ppa list and "Reading package lists... Done".

Comment: Looks like you've got an issue with those repositories, if you go into Software & Updates and disable all the ones listen to have a problem and then try running the command again does that help? You can enable them again afterwards. Although it doesn't look like they're working.

Comment: I've finally purged this rep, but it didn't make any difference. I guess the problem might be because I have gnome shell installed? Right now I got the default font changed somehow by itself, the theme has changed to ambiance (I had radiance) and I cannot change it back, global menu sometimes doubles with local menu in windows, and as I was typing this, I launched nautilus and it crashed, with desktop icons disappearing.

Comment: After relaunching nautilus the program now completely ignores my left close/max/min button placement (and so does calendar, but not firefox or telegram). And libreoffice, jtest-gtk look like it's 90s.

Comment: So did you have Unity and then also install GNOME Shell for this? Because that's highly inadvisable due to big incompatibilities with doing it that way rather than freshly installing the new flavour. I know because I went through hell with this at one stage.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. I guess I'd rather reinstall the os now. Wish there would be more info on this issue, albeit really doesn't matter a lot now, since unity is leaving.

Comment: @ThomasJanowsky: Sorry to say this, but reinstalling really would be the best idea, otherwise you'll have to do a lot of manual unpicking of the system. When I did this I just had to do a reinstall in the end because it had changed all the configuration and partly broken Unity as well so it would take ages to fix and be near impossible to find all of the changes.